# Как правильно подключить Поведение в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем здравствуйте, есть класс описывающий поведение.

```
public class OpenBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            AssociatedObject.MouseDoubleClick += MouseDuobleCli;
        }

        private void MouseDuobleCli(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("fdgsdg");
        }



        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();

            AssociatedObject.MouseDoubleClick -= MouseDuobleCli;
        }

    }
```

Есть разметка.

```
<Window x:Class="wpf_arcer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_arcer"
        xmlns:customObjects="clr-namespace:wpf_arcer.ModelView"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"


        mc:Ignorable="d"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772">
            <TabItem Name="Parse" Header="Парсинг">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="62*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="17*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="11*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="663*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="351" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="725" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                        <Label Content="Список категорий" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="27,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Button Command="{Binding CommandToRun}" Content="Получить список категорий" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="28,326,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Grid.Column="4"/>
                    <Label Content="Глубина парсинга" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="297,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" Grid.Column="4"/>
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="436,47,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding NumberPages, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67" Grid.Column="4"/>
                    <Button  Command="{Binding CommandToPars}" Content="Парсить выбранные страницы" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="368,326,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="188" Grid.Column="4"/>
                    <customObjects:CustomListBox x:Name="ListBox"  SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding Rubrikses, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedItemsList="{Binding SelectedPlanshets, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Margin="0,47,449,55" ></customObjects:CustomListBox>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Name="Data" Header="Данные">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="361" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="722">

                        <DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="237" Margin="31,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="648"></DataGrid>


                        <Button Command="{Binding CommandGetDataFromBase}" Content="Получить данные из базы" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="227,301,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249"/>
                        <Label Content="Поиск  в базе" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="31,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="134,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FilterText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="545"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>


        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

В разметке в области  TabItem Name="Data" Header="Данные" есть Datagrid, хочу подключить поведение,ссылка на System.Windows.Interactivity подключена. Вопрос а как мне в коде указать это поведение, беру примеры из сети, но не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
 <DataGrid>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:OpenBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

где `local` это подключенное пространство имен, где лежит ваше поведение. Например:

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProject.Behaviors">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Увы не работает в моей верстке не работает,в примере который я написал,в моей датагрид уже есть данные,вставлю вашу конструкцию датагрид не работает

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, Должно работать, другого варианта нет. Отредактируйте вопрос. Уберите лишнее из вашего кода и приведите [МСВП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ?да работает я вижу , но я не могу в своей верстке,которая приведена в примере,как мне вставить это поведение, если у меня датагрид вот такой <DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="237" Margin="31,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="648"></DataGrid>

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, Так в чем проблема? Делаете ровно также, как я указал, между тегами <DataGrid></DataGrid> подключаете поведение. Добавьте в вопрос пример кода, как вы пытаетесь подключить поведение.

Comment: ок все заработало, спасибо